# How to set x axis according to the numbers in the DATAFRAME

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

i am using Matplotlib to show graph of some information that i get from the users,
i want to show it as:axis x will be by the ID of the users and axis y will be by the Winning time that whey have..
I dont understand how can i put the x axis index as the ID of my users.
my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib,pylab as pylab
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
#df = pd.read_csv('Players.csv')
df = pd.read_json('Players.json')
# df.groupby('ID').sum()['Win']
axisx = df.groupby('ID').sum()['Win'].keys()
axisy = df.groupby('ID').sum()['Win'].values


fig = pylab.gcf()
# fig.canvas.set_window_title('4 In A Row Statistic')
# img = plt.imread("Oi.jpeg")
# plt.imshow(img)



fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xticklabels(axisx.to_list())
plt.title('Game Statistic',fontsize=20,color='r')
plt.xlabel('ID Players',color='r')
plt.ylabel('Wins',color='r')

x = np.arange(len(axisx))
rects = ax.bar(x, axisy, width=0.1)


plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

use `plt.xticks(array_of_id)`. `xticks` can set the current tick locations and labels of the x-axis.